Getting INFINITE_LOOP_DETECTED as response while calling vercel api
I am calling vercel API to get a deployment details from GitHub Actions workflow.
Here's my code:
- name: Get deployment details
  run: |
    curl -L -X GET "https://api.vercel.com/v13/deployments/${{ steps.build-and-deploy.outputs.DEPLOYMENT_URL }}?slug=***&teamId=***&withGitRepoInfo=true" \
      -H "Authorization: Bearer ${{ secrets.VERCEL_TOKEN }}" -H "Content-Type: application/json"

and ${{ steps.build-and-deploy.outputs.DEPLOYMENT_URL }} is the deployment URL which is working properly. When called this API, got INFINITE_LOOP_DETECTED as response. What's going wrong in this code?
Links to refer: https://vercel.com/docs/rest-api/endpoints/deployments#get-a-deployment-by-id-or-url

Can this step be called multiple times according to the rest of your workflow implementation? Also, did you try following the troubleshoot section for this error on Vercel doc?

Yep, step can be called multiple times and also I had tried all the steps mentioned in trouble shoot section on Vercel doc @GuiFalourd

Yep, step can be called multiple times. It is possible for this step to be called in loop and generate this error message? (if there is a push triggering a new workflow run for example, of behaviors like that)

@GuiFalourd Gave the whole context of the workflow.

Based on what you share alone, it seems not to be possible to generate an INFINITE_LOOP_DETECTED error. Can this pipeline be triggered in parallel by multiple event at the same time? Or do you have other integrations with this Vercel API endpoint (https://api.vercel.com/v13/deployments/) in other part of your processes that may be generating this amount of requests?

Yes, this pipeline can be triggered in parallel at same time. The workflow is reusable workflow. But only push event triggers the workflow. I do not have other integrations with this  Vercel API endpoint.

When triggered in parallel, I imagine the DEPLOYMENT_URL, slug and teamId are different in every run, right? Do you also use the same VERCEL_TOKEN when calling this https://api.vercel.com/v13/deployments/... URL?

@GuiFalourd DEPLOYMENT_URL is different but slug and teamId are same in every run. Yes same VERCEL_TOKEN is being used.

I'm out of idea here, I asked chat gpt some insights based on the question and the context we added here, and got this answer if you want to have a look. It seems to cover all we discussed here as well.

Apologies for the confusion. The issue arose from a mistake on my part. I was including "https://" in the deployment URL within the API request. After removing "https://" and then appending the deployment URL to the API request, it worked correctly and Many thanks to @GuiFalourd grateful for your support.
